# How to do a full text search, when content has HTML tags?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to make a full-text search using text content in HTML format. E.g.:

```
... f<em>oo</em> ...
```

If the search term will be 'foo' the document containing "f*oo*" will not be found

How to make this work?

I'm using PostgreSQL

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid you won't find anything out of the box, but you could extract text from your html column, e.g. using regular expressions or xpath (designed for xml)

```
CREATE TABLE t (html text);
INSERT INTO t VALUES ('<html>
  <h1>
    <foo>test f<em>oo</em> bar</foo>
  </h1>
  <h1>
    <foo>test bar</foo>
  </h1>
 </html>');

SELECT * FROM t
WHERE to_tsvector(regexp_replace(html,'<.+?>','','g')) @@ plainto_tsquery('test foo');

                 html                 
--------------------------------------
 <html>                              +
   <h1>                              +
     <foo>test f<em>oo</em> bar</foo>+
   </h1>                             +
   <h1>                              +
     <foo>test bar</foo>             +
   </h1>                             +
  </html>
```

Keep in mind that creating the ts_vector in query time will make things quite slow. So, if you decided to go this way consider creating a new column for it and then create a gin index, e.g.

```
CREATE INDEX idx_html_tsvector ON t USING gin(the_new_column);
```

Demo: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=feb8782642bf01c5d1f546eb7a0e1c60)

Answer (score 0):

The PostgreSQL text parser will recognize tags but considers them as ending words, so it will parse that as 'f' and 'oo'.  This cannot be changed without hacking the C code.  You could implement your own parser, but again in C, and doing so is not easy.  Your best bet is probably to pre-process your text with something else to remove the tag, making sure that closes up the gap to give 'foo', not 'f oo'.

Comment: Honestly, I had no idea. I think it's basically implied by the list of textsearch-parsers separating "asciiword" from "tag" but I don't think anywhere explicitly says it will "just work (probably) exactly how you want it to". Incredible piece of software. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/textsearch-parsers.html